# Racket - require an entire directory of files

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, require

Currently I have to do this at the top of every file:

```
(require "dynamore/dynamore.rkt")
(require "dynamore/db.rkt")
(require "dynamore/types.rkt")
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
(require dynamore)
```

Preferably without having to develop my own collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you prefer not to create a package (which means you need to `require` relatively):

1. If `dynamore` contains only those three files, you can use `reprovide-lang`'s [`glob-in`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reprovide/index.html?q=glob-in#%28form._%28%28lib._reprovide%2Frequire-transformer%2Fglob-in..rkt%29._glob-in%29%29) as follows: `(require (glob-in "dynamore/*.rkt"))`.
2. You can also create `main.rkt` in `dynamore` that uses [the main functionality](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reprovide/index.html?q=reprovide#%28mod-path._reprovide%29) of `reprovide-lang` to specifically reprovide only those three files:

   ```
   #lang reprovide
   "dynamore.rkt"
   "db.rkt"
   "types.rkt"
   ```

   To use it, simply `(require "dynamore/main.rkt")`.

   - A native solution that doesn't use `reprovide-lang` would be to use [`all-from-out`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._all-from-out%29%29) manually:

     ```
     #lang racket/base
     (require "dynamore.rkt"
              "db.rkt"
              "types.rkt")
     (provide (all-from-out "dynamore.rkt"
                            "db.rkt"
                            "types.rkt"))
     ```

If you prefer to create a package, then follow Solution 2 above (create `main.rkt`, etc.), create `info.rkt` in the `dynamore` directory as follows:

```
#lang info
(define collection "dynamore")
```

Then run `raco pkg install`. From now on, you will be able to `(require dynamore)` from anywhere.

Note: to install `reprovide-lang`, run `raco pkg install reprovide-lang`.

Comment: as an aside, you don't need 3 different `all-from-outs`, you can put all 3 files within just 1 `all-from-out` like `(provide (all-from-out "dynamore.rkt" "db.rkt" "types.rkt"))`

Comment: Edited! Also, @AlexKnauth is the author of `reprovide-lang`. Thanks for the wonderful package!

Comment: Thank you so much for the information packed answer!